# Callback from jQuery not getting to Controller/Action

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have a contact us form in a modal dialog box using jQuery in an MVC application.  The box popups up fine, but when I click on the submit button in the dialog box, its not getting to my action method.  I've tried a few things, but can't figure out what's wrong.  Can someone see what I might be doing wrong?  Thanks.

PartialView (Contact Us form):

```
@model BackgroundSoundBiz.Models.EmailModel

<form id="sendEmailForm">
    <div id="sendForm">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.senderName)<br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.senderName)
        <br />
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.senderEmail)<br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.senderEmail)
        <br />
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.message)<br />
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.message)
        <br />
        <input class="close" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Model:

```
    public class EmailModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string senderName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string senderEmail { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Message")]
        public string message { get; set; }
    }
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".openDialog").on("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("<div></div>").addClass("dialog")
                    .attr("id", $(this).attr("data-dialog-id"))
                    .appendTo("body")
                    .dialog({
                        title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
                        close: function () { $(this).remove() },
                        width: 500,
                        height: 350,
                        show: { effect: "blind", duration: 1000 },
                        hide: { effect: "explode", duration: 1000 },
                        modal: true
                    }).load(this.href);
            });

            $(".close").on("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var senderName = $("#Name").val();
                var senderEmail = $("#Email").val();
                var message = $("#Message").text();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Home/SendEmail",
                    data: { "senderName": senderName, "senderEmail": senderEmail, "message": message },
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("Your email was successfully sent.");
                        $(this).closest(".dialog").dialog("close");
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        alert("There was an error sending your email.  Please try again or contact system administrator.");
                        $(this).closest(".dialog").dialog("close");
                    }
                })
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Controller:

```
        public ActionResult SendEmail()
        {
            return PartialView("SendEmail", new EmailModel());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SendEmail(EmailModel model)
        {
            bool isSuccessful = true;

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //send email
            }

            return Json(isSuccessful);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dynamically adding the form to the DOM using `.load(this.href);` which means you need to use event delegation to handle the button. Change

```
$(".close").on("click", function (e) {
```

to

```
$(document).on('click', '.close', function(e) {`
```

although you should replace `document` with the closest ancestor that exists on the page when you first render the view.

In addition, your jQuery selectors are incorrect and you will not be posting any values related to your model. The correct selectors are based on the `id` attributes generated by the `HtmlHelper` methods are

```
var senderName = $("#senderName").val();
var senderEmail = $("#senderEmail").val();
var message = $("#message").val();
```

however its better to use the `.serialize()` method which will correctly serialize your form controls

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("SendEmail", "Home")', // don't hard code
    data: $('#sendEmailForm').serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
        ....
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen.  You're the man!  The only thing, my data didn't get to the controller.  I'm assuming that my "data" attribute isn't formatted right.  Is that correct?

Comment: The format is OK (although you do not need to quote the property names) But a textarea does not have a `.text()` property. It needs to be `var message = $("#Message").val();`

Comment: Was the above the only issues you saw?  Tried your suggestions and another one I found and the data still isn't being passed to the controller.

Comment: Refer edited answer pointing out other errors with your code.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, it worked.  I did have the jQuery selectors right in the beginning but I changed them trying prior to posting the original problem.  Once again, I appreciate your help.